# Cruz T301: USB Storage Not Recognized

Tags: usb, 2.2-froyo, sd-card

I have a Cruz Tablet (T301) that runs Android 2.2.1.  I do not remember if my tablet originally came with a cord or not, but I have a cord that originally goes to a camera of mine that fits both the USB port and the port that fits my tablet, and so used it to connect to the computer.  Upon doing so, I received the notification to turn on my USB storage on my tablet device, which I did.  However, even though my USB storage is in use, I noticed that my computer did not recognize my tablet as a removable storage.

Is my tablet not allowed to connect to computers to be recognized as removable storage?  If not, what do I have to do so the computer will recognize my tablet?  If my computer does recognize my tablet, where do I go to find it on the computer so I can transfer files, since it is not showing up under the devices and drives sector of the computer?

I do not know if this will be helpful, but I've noticed that the only thing that has been working is the tablet's registration of charge: it seems to be charging just fine.

Upon rising to my suspicion, I thought about if it had anything to do with the SD card.  Safely removing it, I turned the SD card over to an adapter, hoping that maybe a more direct link will do something.  Much to my dismay, I saw nothing.  I remember changing the format or something of that nature of one of the SD cards on my phone, and my phone is an Android 2.3.  I think that was the SD card, but did I make a mistake doing so?

Comment: Do you have the latest USB drivers for the T301 installed?

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not even sure if I have the latest USB drivers for the T301.  What are the latest USB drivers, and if I don't have it, where can I get it?

Comment: Download driver near the bottom of this page: http://www.cruztablet.com/Cruz_downloads.php

Comment: When I reached the [page you navigated to me](http://www.cruztablet.com/Cruz_downloads.php), I clicked the [Cruz Tablet Firmware Update Utility](http://www.cruztablet.com/vm_cruz_T10X-FUU_v1.3.exe), [T301 Tweak Tool](http://www.cruztablet.com/vm_cruz_T301-Tweak_v1.exe), and [Android ADB USB Driver](http://s3.velocitymicro.com/vmcruz/drivers/ADB_usb_driver.zip): none of the links required me to download anything.  However, I have been able to reach the [T301 Update](http://www.cruztablet.com/Article_861.php): should I try that first before I use any of the other lower links?

Comment: Sorry, was out of town for a week. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click those links and manually download or here is the [full link for USB driver](http://s3.velocitymicro.com/vmcruz/drivers/ADB_usb_driver.zip).

[Read this article on how to install the drivers.](http://www.cruzreader.com/Article_858.php)

After installing the drivers, see if you can see the Cruz from your PC. If not, reformat the SD card in the T301, put it in your PC, and copy a file to it. Then back in the Cruz and see if you can at least see the file. Though not a direct solution, at least you will be able to copy files back and forth.

If that does not work, try the same process with a different SD card. If that still does not work, try formatting an SD card in the PC, copy a file to it, then put it the Cruz. The idea is to get you to the point where *something* works.